# How to format time using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to format time which will be entered by the user. I am showing one textbox in which user can enter the time. I want to format the number like this:

If user enters 1, format like this:

```
 1.00
```

If user enters 11, format like this:

```
 11.00
```

If user enters 11:03, format like this:

```
 11.03
```

If user enters 111, format like this:

```
 1.11
```

If user enters 1111, format like this:

```
11.11
```

How to do this?

Comment: Your 4th format looks illogical.

Comment: @KunJ It's not illogical, it's a specification.

Comment: @dystroy apologies for illogical word, I want to say that 111 can be 11.10 as well as 1.11

Comment: @KunJ It's a time, with optionally minutes. It doesn't feel so strange to let people enter either a time without minutes or a time with minutes (then, you require the whole minutes number).

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any magical solution, you have to program the logic you see.

This would do :

```
function a(s){
  return '00'.slice((''+s).length)+s;
}
function f(n){
  var bc = Math.floor(n/100), ac = n%100; // gets the two parts
  if (!bc) { // adjust if there's no right part
    bc = ac;
    ac = 0;
  }
  return a(bc)+'.'+a(ac);
}
```

Test :

```
[1, 11, 103, 1103, 1111].forEach(function(n){
  console.log(n, '->', f(n));
});
```

logs

```
1 "->" "01.00" 
11 "->" "11.00" 
103 "->" "01.03" 
1103 "->" "11.03"
1111 "->" "11.11"
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code is the working solution.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>time</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function get()
{
var t=prompt("ente time");
var result=1.00;
if(t.length==4)
{
result=(parseFloat(t)/100)*1.00;

}
else if(t.length==3)
result=(parseFloat(t)/100)*1.00;
else if(t.length==2)
 result=t.concat(".00");
else if(t.length==1)
  result=t.concat(".00");

else if(t.indexOf(":")!=-1)
{
  result=t.substring(0,2)+"."+t.substring(3,5);
}
alert(result);

}
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="get()">

</body>
</html>
```